# Get Session variables when calling from Winforms to ASP.NET web

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, session-variables

I have a web site wherein I can open an exe, using a custom registered URI scheme. This exe or msi installer is a winform which acts like a self hosted web api, where it gets parameters from an Ajax call made from a website.

So this is my Jquery call from website:

```
var appParameters = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/parameters/digital',
        accepts: 'application/json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data: appParameters,
        success: function () {
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:8090/Home/Enroll";
        },
        onerror: function () {

        }
        });
```

And this call is made to my winform which acts like a self hosted web api.

Hosting logic is the following:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");

        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API Default",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new MainForm(new ApiValueObserable<AppParameters>()));
        }
```

and this my ajax hitting point:

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Digital(string redirectPage, string redirectErrorPage, string responsePage, string successMessage)
    {
        var appParameter = new AppParameters
        {
            RedirectPage = redirectPage,
            RedirectErrorPage = redirectErrorPage,
            ResponsePage = responsePage,
            SuccessMessage = successMessage,                
        };

        ApiValueObserable<AppParameters>.Update(appParameter);

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = null
        };
    }
```

After some operation I hit the server code form winforms using following code:

```
var dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(employee.ToString());

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:51953/Home/Contact");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        //httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        //httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");            

        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;

        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        Stream dataStream = await httpWebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();

        dataStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        dataStream.Flush();
        dataStream.Close();
```

My concern here is that I have to create an intermediary bypass page when traversing back from winform to website, because I cannot pass credentials to website as it uses "**Forms Authentication**". This intermediary web page cannot retrieve any Session variables which is there on the server.

So I want to know any suggestions / approach for a redirection logic I can do from this intermediary web page to another web page so it gets all Session variables, or any way I can get Session variables stored on the server side, through this intermediary web page.

Any help would be great.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Comment: Anyone any help or recommendations?.

Comment: Or just to re-frame the question how can we achieve SSO from winform to web app. Any samples available for the same??

Comment: Guys any help on this or no one has any idea??